# Using doMock on default imports

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios

For some reason, I could not mock my httpService no matter what configurations I do in jest. When the test runs, it still tries to connect to the real backend. I know that because I am getting an error like this from the terminal

```
  ● call to add task endpoint

    connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000
```

Here are my files:

taskService.test.ts

```
import task from "./taskService";

beforeEach(() => jest.resetModules());

test("call to add task endpoint", async () => {
  jest.doMock("./httpService", () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: {
      post: jest.fn(() => {}),
    },
  }));

  const httpService = require("./httpService");

  await task.add("Go To Market", "2021-02-28");

  expect(httpService.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/tasks", {
    task: "Go To Market",
    date: "2021-02-28",
  });
});
```

taskService.ts

```
import httpService from "./httpService";

const add = async (task: string, date: string) => {
  await httpService.post("/tasks", {
    date,
    task,
  });
};

export default {
  add,
};
```

httpService.ts

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  get: axios.get,
  post: axios.post,
  put: axios.put,
  delete: axios.delete,
};
```

The folder structure looks like this:

```
services
  - httpService.ts
  - taskService.test.ts
  - taskService.ts
```

Comment: task uses original httpService. You have to import it inside the test either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the mock to work properly, it should be in the same scope as the `require/import` statement (in this case, the `taskService` import). This means we can't use [`jest.doMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) since it does not get hoisted above the `import` statement like [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) does. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64247239/3724716) to understand the difference between `jest.mock` and `jest.doMock`.

```js
import task from './taskService'
import httpService from './httpService'

jest.mock('./httpService', () => ({
  post: jest.fn(),
}))

beforeEach(() => jest.resetModules())

test('call to add task endpoint', async () => {
  await task.add('Go To Market', '2021-02-28')

  expect(httpService.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/tasks', {
    task: 'Go To Market',
    date: '2021-02-28',
  })
})
```

Comment: Oh so either I import the taskService inside the test block or I move the httpService to the top. It can't be a mixture? I hope I got it right. Thank you very much!

Comment: @lueenavarro If you do want to use `jest.doMock` inside the test block, you could use `require` to import the `taskService` module (make sure to use `require('./taskService').default` since the module has default exports) after the `jest.doMock` call (`jest.doMock` calls are not hoisted to the top of the code block). Your `httpService` import needs to be fixed as well - `require('./httpService').default`. Note that the mock should always be in the same scope as the import. The order in which you import the module and set up the mock matters if you're using `jest.doMock`.

Comment: Thank you! I can now understand what's happening