# How to make a jest mock reusable?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, i18next

I Have the below jest mock which mocks the react-i18next.

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  useTranslation: () => {
    return {
      t: (str: string, { ns, defaultValue }) => defaultValue,
      i18n: {
        changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
      },
    };
  },
  initReactI18next: {
    type: '3rdParty',
    init: () => {},
  },
}));
```

I tried to make it reusable by creating a new file for it like below. But importing and running MyReusableMockFunction doesnt mock the react-i18next in the spec file. what could be going wrong here? what are the alternatives to make this mock reusable

```
import {jest} from '@jest/globals'
export const MyReusableMockFunction=()=>{
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  useTranslation: () => {
    return {
      t: (str: string, { ns, defaultValue }) => defaultValue,
      i18n: {
        changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
      },
    };
  },
  initReactI18next: {
    type: '3rdParty',
    init: () => {},
  },
}));
}
```

Comment: It's likely a matter of _timing_. Mocks need to be registered _before_ the actual import happens, which is why they: 1. Need to be at the top level of the module; and 2. Get hoisted by Jest.

Comment: i am running the MyReusableMockFunction(); as the first line in my specfile after imports , i also tried to run it in the beforeall() as well but both are not working

Comment: Yes, but that's _after imports_ so it's too late.

Comment: but why do you want to mock it instead of [making i18n config for testing](https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing#testing-without-stubbing)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to mock i18n globally. The easiest way to do that is by adding it to your jest.setup.js file. It is then mocked for all your tests (we use i18next instead of react-i18next so the actual mock might differ):

```
jest.doMock('i18next', () => ({
  use: () => ({
    init: jest.fn(),
  }),
  changeLanguage: () => {
    return Promise.resolve();
  },
  /**
   * Mocks the t function of i18next
   * If you pass parameters to the t function they will be stringified and added to the key.
   */
  t: (key, parameters) => (parameters ? key + JSON.stringify(parameters) : key),
}));
```

If you don't want to use it in a testFile for whatever reason, you can unmock it:

```
jest.unmock('i18next');
```

Here is also an interesting answer about hoisting with mock doMock unmock and dontMock: [Difference between jest.mock and jest.doMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64245013/difference-between-jest-mock-and-jest-domock)